# C# GET Request and Parsing JSON

Tags: c#, json, get, request

I am developing Windows store app in Windows 8, Visual Studio 2012. I need to make GET request to a particular URL and get the JSON as response. And I need to parse the JSON to get the values in it. I need C# code to do the above functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this sample code from [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/db466fde-9056-4d01-b46d-cfa49c312c02/)

```
    var client = new HttpClient();
        var uri = new Uri("http://ponify.me/stats.php");
        Stream respStream = await client.GetStreamAsync(uri);
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(rootObject));
        rootObject feed = (rootObject)ser.ReadObject(respStream);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(feed.SONGHISTORY[0].TITLE);
```

Comment: I am using above code. It is working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You could use the [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) class. The [GetAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158944.aspx) method allows you to send a GET request to a specified url:

```
public async Task<JsonObject> GetAsync(string uri)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var content = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
    return await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Parse(content));
}
```

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov Hey, I have written code up to getting response. I need to know how to get JSON from response and parse the JSON.

Comment: @Ramesh: So why not just ask a question about parsing? And say in your question that you already have the response string?

Comment: @Ramesh, that's exactly what I have shown in my answer. Did you read it? You use the GetAsync method to send a GET request and then the `JsonObject.Parse` method to parse the returned JSON string.

Comment: @musefan Actually I already had for POST. Just now figured out I can reuse for GET also.

Comment: @musefan, answering a question depends on my mood. Now I am in a good mood, so I answer all kind of questions.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Visual Studio complains about the return type it should be a `JsonValue` instead of a `JsonObject`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov This is bad code as it blocks a background thread, I reproduced your code and it blocked my application, see: https://www.ben-morris.com/why-you-shouldnt-create-asynchronous-wrappers-with-task-run/